# How to fix "Password management, empty password"?

Tags: c#, security, passwords, fortify

HP fortify [document](https://vulncat.hpefod.com/en/detail?id=desc.semantic.java.password_management_null_password#C%23%2FVB.NET%2FASP.NET) warns me that the following code would has some security problems:

```
string storedPassword = "";
string temp;

if ((temp = ReadPassword(storedPassword)) != null) {
    storedPassword = temp;
}

if(Utils.VerifyPassword(storedPassword, userPassword))
    // Access protected resources
    ...
}
```

If *readPassword()* fails to retrieve the stored password due to a database error or another problem, then an attacker could trivially bypass the password check by providing an empty string for *userPassword*.

ok... I agree with the instruction... but how to fix the problem ? what is the best practice for the code to handle the password management ?

Comment: And what's the point of that `temp` variable and useless null checks? Why not just `string storedPassword = ReadPassword()`? Then you might check `storedPassword` for null, though I cannot imagine any sane implementation of `ReadPassword` to return null on failure instead of throwing exception. It's not C after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` statement:

```
public bool VerifyPassword(string storedPassword, string userPassword)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userPassword))
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't initialize your password (in this case to empty string) until you have a valid password value.

```
string storedPassword;
//string storedPassword = null;
string temp;

if ((temp = ReadPassword(storedPassword)) != null) {
    storedPassword = temp;
}

if(Utils.VerifyPassword(storedPassword, userPassword))
    // Access protected resources
    ...
}
```

Comment: Without initializing the password, it will be flagged as "Password Management: Null Password"